# How merge values of Mono in loop?

Tags: java, project-reactor, java.util.concurrent, reactive-streams

I have a list of entities `List<Entity1>` like

```
public class Entity1 {
    private int id;
    ....
}
```

I need to iterate over this list, apply my function and get `Mono<Entity2>` based on each Entity1. So, I will have a `List<Mono<Entity2>>`.

Then I need to merge this second list to `Mono<List<Entity2>>`

I do not know by which way I can get `List<Mono<Entity2>>` and then `Mono<List<Entity2>>`.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not by which way I can get `List<Mono<Entity2>>` and then `Mono<List<Entity2>>`

Once you have your `List<Mono<Entity2>>`, you can just do:

```
Flux.concat(list).collectList();
```

...to obtain a `Mono<List<Entity2>>`. This concatenates your list of Monos into a single Flux, then collects the items in that resulting Flux back into a list.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It helped me.
Firstly, I just added all monos to the list `List<Mono<Entity2>>`.
Secondly, I flatted them to single list by this way:
`Flux.concat(monos)
                   .collectList()
                   .map(list -> {
                       List<Entity2> all = list.stream()
                                              .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
                       return all;
                   });`